# Error: 'python35_d.dll is missing' while running C++ code with Python in MS Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, python-3.x, dll

I am trying to embed Python in my C++ code to use WordNet through nltk. I am new to Python and I am using MS Visual Studio 2015 to do the same but I'm facing problems to use Python on MSVS 15.

So far I've,

- installed Python 3.5.1,
- included this path: `...\Python\Python35-32\include`, which let me include the `Python.h` library,
- added this path: `...\Python\Python35-32\libs` to access the lib files, and `python35.lib` as dependency in `Linker\Input` setting of MSVS15,
- then there an error occurred, demanding `python35_d.lib`, so I compiled Python's source in `Debug` mode & copied that file to that `...\libs` folder and it solved the problem.

This all happened when I was trying to run this only-

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("print (\"Hello World!\\n\")");
Py_Finalize();
```

Now I'm trying to run a Python function from a `.py` file. I'm trying to run [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding) from the [Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/index.html) but I'm getting this error -

[image]

While debugging, I have found that when this macro gets called: `Py_DECREF()`, this error occurs.

Do I only need to copy `python35_d.dll` from `PCBuild\win32` to `C:\Windows\[System|System32|SysWOW64]\` to solve the problem as I don't know if it'll have any side-effects?

Although the file is already present in `...\Python\Python35-32\DLLs\`.

Is there a proper setup to be done before running Python in C/C++ using MSVS, like [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems) for Unix-like systems? (I mean by adding other dependencies or folders to the settings)

I've been reading Python documentation continuously and even other stackoverflow questions but I'm still struggling a lot (I don't know why) even to do simple things.

Can somebody guide/enlighten me for something I may be missing because I'm continuously getting errors here & there, please?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to copy the dll to the folder where your binary is built.

Comment: @DavidMarquant: Thanks, it worked fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

copy python35.dll into the folder where .sln file is present

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not a forum, please keep the structure of it. This is more a comment than an answer. When you have enough reputation you can post comment.

Comment: @EliasMP I disagree. He attempted to answer the question it might not be correct. See comment by *David Marquant* on the question. This answer could be considered *LQ* though.