# ImportError: No module named '...', unable add path to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, environment-variables

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216623/error-python35-d-dll-is-missing-while-running-c-code-with-python-in-ms-visu) is what I'm trying to do.

But after that problem resolved, I had this error: `ImportError: No module named 'multiply'`. What I could figure out was that I had to add the location of my module to `PYTHONPATH`.

I couldn't find `PYTHONPATH` in `System variables` list, so I created one (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)), added all the paths including the one I needed, but it didn't solve the problem.

So, I re-installed all the features of Python, even the ones I didn't earlier. Everywhere I read solutions, there is only written `set this like this` or something similar but no-one says where they are defined or how they work.

Hence my question arises why can't I find [variables](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables) like `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME` in `System variables` while Python [says](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables) they can be set or where are they defined?

Can anyone explain how do environment variables (mentioned in Python's documentation) work?

How can I solve my 'ImportError`?

Comment: What makes you think that the installer sets these variables? (It doesn't.)

Comment: Just because they can be set doesn't mean they are set.  "How do environment variables work" isn't a Python question, and it's also a question you can probably answer yourself by searching the internet.

Answer (score 3):

The installer might not have set those automatically. You can set them yourself in the command prompt if you like:

```
SET variableName = value
```

Or, if you use PowerShell:

```
$env:variableName = value
```

If you don't want to use system commands at all, it can be done from within python with the os module:

```
import os
os.environ[variableName] = value
```

---

If they are already set, but you want to add something to it, the process is a little different. Let's suppose the path you are trying to add to PYTHONPATH is `path`.

Using the command prompt:

```
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;path
```

Python:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] + ";path"
```

---

If you are correct and this is happening because the module is not on PYTHONPATH, this should add it onto the path and fir the problem.
If it doesn't fix the `ImportError`, then the environment variables are probably not the issue.

Links to learn more about environment variables:

- http://www.digitalcitizen.life/simple-questions-what-are-environment-variables
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable
- http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/envivari.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't use `os.putenv`. Use `os.environ[variableName] = value`

Comment: Is it bad practice or something?

Comment: Changes to the environment made using `os.putenv` are not reflected in `os.environ`, which will confuse other python code reading the environment.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Is there something special about `os.environ` so that when it is changed it modifies the system values?

Comment: Yes. `os.enivron` isn't an actual dictionary. It's a dictionary-like object which copies all changes to the environment.

Comment: @ppperry Can you tell me how to access or where `PYTHONPATH` is listed?  Because when I run `SET` command from cmd, it isn't listed there.

Comment: @PalashV the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` is not always defined. When `PYTHONPATH` is not defined or you use the `-E` flag, python will initialize `sys.path` with default values.

Comment: @ppperry Can I set these flags from Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: @PalashV What I mean by the `-E` flag is running the python script as `python -E [other args]`

Comment: Can you add that to the answer?

Comment: @ppperry Can you tell me from the question what am I missing? I mean do we need to manually set up env-vars, because I've seen everywhere how to change their values, but not where/how they are defined? Is there a need to setup  the environment manually.

Comment: @PalashV  No, `PYTHON*` environment variables do not need to be set up to run python.

Comment: @ppperry I know there is some problem with my understanding but can you refer/guide me some source where I can read more the usage of env-vars in Py, apart from the reference from documentation. Or provide a solution to the `ImportError` so that I would be able to relate more what is happening, please.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman: Hi Xamuel. I was trying to add `path` to `PYTHONPATH` from outside the Python. I had done what you wrote (through cmd) but it only created an env-var `PYTHONPATH` with value same as string literal `%PYTHONPATH%;path` (by using `SET` command), and it wasn't even getting mentioned in the list of `User variables` or `System variables`, so I thought `Python` would be initializing it. In the end, I added my file to the `PythonNN\` folder to run my project. I still don't have a clear understanding of how this all works, so I need to give it more time. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @PalashV Well, I hope you can figure it out. Glad to be of help to you. ;)